# jQuery mobile refresh button

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am having problems when I add new content to the database the pages are not updated. So I was thinking of adding a refresh button.

Hope can I do this please?

Comment: Please [don’t use signatures or taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your posts. Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page

Comment: doubt window.reload() will not work????

Comment: @Sathya which signatures you are talking about???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to refresh the page.  You just need to call `location.reload(true)`.

By setting the first (and only) argument to `true` we *force* a refresh from the server, and not just reload the page from the cache.

Comment: How do I use it please? For example, where on the page to I place it?

Comment: @Satch3000: `<button onclick="location.reload(true)">Reload the page</button>`?

Comment: for some weird reason, sometimes you have to do this: setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);},1);

Answer (score 10):

The problem you are having has to do with how jQuery **Mobile** caches pages. And `location.reload(true)` **Will Not Work** as the URL will have a hash string.

### Reason:

In order to emulate native mobile transitions jQuery Mobile performs a Ajax request and inserts the `<div data-role="page">` element inside the **first** page, essentially creating a single page site from a muti-page one (with navigation, bookmarking built into it).

### solution:

However the team has lacked a little foresight into how to deal with time dependent content. I personally have fixed the issue by adding a attribute to my links that I want to get a **fresh copy**.

```
$('body').delegate('a[data-cache=false]', 'click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    $('[data-url="' + $this.attr('href') + '"]' ).remove();
    
});
```

This listens to a click event (tap, whatever), **removes the cached div** and lets jQuery request a fresh copy.

### Note:

There are over solutions to this such a `data-ajax="false"` and `rel="extenal"` however these will stop the navigation system to functionality to function to it's full extent. Also the jQuery team is aware of the issues surrounding this and are currently working of a full navigation rewrite. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/13/jquery-mobile-team-update-week-of-may-9th/.